# Determine where function is discontinuous by its fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

The fourier coefficients of ${f} \in C_{PW}^0$ are given by
$\widehat f(n)=(-i)^n(\frac{3i}{4n}+\frac{1}{2\pi n^2}) $
for $n \ne 0$.

Find where $f$ is discontinuous and what is its jump there?

it's enough to find estimates to the exact answer.

Honestly i don't know how to even start.

Comment: Finding the exact answer might be the simplest way to go, as this a sum of known Fourier series I think

Comment: Actually i thought about it too but i couldn't find any known fourier series which matches those fourier coefficients, there is a table of fourier series here http://www.math.chalmers.se/~mohammad/teaching/0304/TMA682/pdf/Fourier_series.pdf    and quite frankly i don't know any fourier series with the $(-i)^n$ term   @LL 3.14

Comment: Perhaps it might help using the fact that $(-i)^n = cos(\pi\,n)-i\sin(\pi\,n)$, looking at translated versions of your Fourier series $f(\theta+c)$ and then the fact that $\sin(n(\theta +c)) = ...$